# Не могу получит ключ с QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Сравниваю containce в QMap показывает ключ есть:

```
if(!(ctrl->mapIp.contains(ctrl->connectAddr.toIPv4Address())))
        return;
```

Перебираю в цикле QMap, вытаскиваю ключ, но он не равен реальному ключу. Почему так? Как мне вытащить ключ?

```
 QMap<qint32, ClientInfo*>::iterator it = ctrl->mapIp.begin();
    for(;it!=ctrl->mapIp.end();it++) {
        qDebug() <<"ctrl->connectAddr1=" <<ctrl->connectAddr.toIPv4Address();
        qDebug() <<"i1=" <<it.key();
    }
```

Вывод:

```
ctrl->connectAddr1= 3232235620
i1= -1062731676
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если сложить `3232235620` и `1062731676` (без минуса), то будет `4294967296`, то в хексе это будет ровно `0x100000000`, что как бы [должно уже намекнуть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

Расширим. Эти два числа - это одно и тоже число, просто в первом случае считаем, что там беззнаковое, а в втором - знаковое. Ключ в мапе у Вас qint32, а функция toIPv4Address имеет следующую сигнатуру `quint32   toIPv4Address() const`.

Как бы я исправил? - поменял бы в определении тип. То есть, мапу объявлял так

```
QMap<quint32, ClientInfo*> mapIp;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я поменял, как вы и сказали, qint32 на quint32 и теперь ключ равен ключу из foreach. Работает.